# Mysql Joining couple tables together

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, inner-join

So lets start from the begining.

I have got 3 tables:

Table apps:

```
apps
id     name      status
-----------------------------
```

Table menu_subsection:

```
menu_subsection
id     app_id    subsection
-----------------------------
```

Table site:

```
site
id  site_name app1 app2 app3 app4 app5 app6 app7 app8 app9 app10 ... app19 app20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

with Table site having columns for app1 through to app20.

For better explanation `site.app1-20` are equal to `apps.id` and also `apps.name` is equal to `menu_subsection.subsection`

Now I want to show `<li>menu_subsection.$subsection</li>` for each `table.site app1-20` column that is equal 1 where

```
apps.status = 1
```

First of all I'm new to mysql and I do appreciate suggestions and maybe if you think it is better to modify tables fine I would do as I would like to make it work in best possible way.

I was also thinkinhg to reduce app1-20 columns and replace this by apps where values will be spread by , coma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site table isn't efficient. With the huge amount of fields! You'd better use 3 fields that is more efficient and provides a good solution for ease of queries!
I also think `apps` and `menu_subsection` tables are equal semantically (with the same fields and the same domain)
So You can get 2 tables like:

apps:

```
apps
id     name      subsection      status
----------------------------------------
```

site:

```
site
id      site_name      app_id
------------------------------
```

Then you can query through these two tables:

```
SELECT subsection FROM apps INNER JOIN site WHERE status = 1
```

Comment: Hmm... Haven't noticed before that I can merge those two tables. Ok so lets say that 1 record in site table will be able to view 2 apps from apps table  that will be seperated by coma in apps instead of app_id column is that the right thinking?

Comment: @PawełGawroński I don't think so. You know when you wanna join 2 tables, you have 2 fields that have identical domain. So if you use coma, you can not join these 2 tables.

Comment: So how can I give possibility to the sites to have access to more than one app?  adding records in site table with the same site_name and different app_id?

Comment: @PawełGawroński Yes. In a such table, your primary key is (site_name and app_id) combination or even id field from site table. It's better than coma solution (bad pattern) which is a deadlock or need some more computations that are not really necessary

Comment: So I have now rebuild the tables as suggested and yup it is working:) a lot easier than in my first solution. Thank you @Pokies